# What does Soil Moisture Profile (%) mean in NASA-USDA Enhanced SMAP Global Soil Moisture Data in Google Earth Engine? How is the % calculated?

Tags: google-earth-engine

What does Soil Moisture Profile (%) mean in NASA-USDA Enhanced SMAP Global Soil Moisture Data in Google Earth Engine?

How is the % calculated?

I searched a lot but did not find the equation or definition of the soil moisture profile (%) for NASA-USDA Enhanced SMAP Global Soil Moisture Data.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the data [description](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NASA_USDA_HSL_SMAP10KM_soil_moisture#description) in the GEE data catalog, there are linked documents explaining what is each variable. For the soil moisture profile [this document](https://gimms.gsfc.nasa.gov/SMOS/SMAP/SoilMoisture_Profile_SMAP.pdf) is linked. It explains that:

> Percent soil moisture is the available water (AW) for the plant
> divided by the total water holding capacity (WHC) of the soil
> profile.

Comment: Thank you, Nicolas. Really appreciate your help. In that document, they did not use the term soil moisture profile rather they used percent soil moisture. That confuses me if they are mentioning the same variable.

Comment: Surface soil moisture is expressed in mm. For percent soil moisture you would need bulk density and specify where ends surface soil (10 cm?, 25 cm?). The assimilation of the SMAP soil moisture observations help improve the model-based soil moisture predictions particularly over poorly instrumented areas of the world that lack good quality precipitation data (it is your case?).

Comment: Thank you, Xunilk